# How can I update the key start from one on the php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

My first array like this :

```
$photoList = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'mu.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'city.jpg'
    )
);
```

My second array like this :

```
photo = array('cover1'=>'liverpool.jpg', 'cover2'=>'city.jpg');
```

My code like this :

```
$photo = array_filter($photo, function($item) use ($photoList) {
   return in_array($item, array_column($photoList, 'name')) ;
});
if (empty($photo)) 
    $photo=null;
```

If I run : `echo '<pre>';print_r($photo);echo '</pre>';`, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [cover2] => city.jpg
)
```

I want the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [cover1] => city.jpg
)
```

So if there is no cover1, the cover2 changed to be cover1

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-index the keys like this :

```
$photoList = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'mu.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'city.jpg'
    )
);
$photo = array('cover1'=>'liverpool.jpg', 'cover2'=>'city.jpg');

$photo = array_filter($photo, function($item) use ($photoList) {
   return in_array($item, array_column($photoList, 'name')) ;
});
if (empty($photo)){
    $photo = null;
} else {
    $idx = 1 ;
    foreach ($photo as $key => $value) {
        unset($photo[$key]);
        $photo['cover'.$idx++] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($photo);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [cover1] => city.jpg
)
```

Comment: Did you try it? I have tried it. But the `$photo` array is same

Comment: The result : `Array
(
    [cover1] => liverpool.jpg
    [cover2] => city.jpg
)`. Should the result : `Array
(
    [cover1] => city.jpg
)`

Comment: @SuccessMan Yes. I've updated the answer with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you really need. Assuming you want to do that recursively, I hope this helps:

```
$label = 'cover';
$index = 1;
$a_keys = array_keys($photo);
$new_photo = [];
foreach($a_keys AS $k=>$v){
    $new_photo[$label.$index] = $photo[$k];
    $index++;
}
$photo = $new_photo;
```

It will rewrite your array with wanted naming style.